# Cannot read from /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier even with sudo

Tags: c, linux, shell, linux-kernel, ethernet

I am trying to write shell script to read the value from /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier but it's giving me the "permission denied" exception . The command I am trying to write in the shell script is

```
sudo echo $(/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier)
```

What I also noticed is that I am getting the same exception when I logged in as root and tried this:

```
echo $(/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier)
```

Any help in trying to read the value executing the shell script is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you have tries to *execute* that file. If you want to contents of the file in a variable, do something like this (probably bash-only syntax):

```
foo=$(</sys/class/net/eth0/carrier)
```

Or (portable)

```
foo=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier)
```

If you just want to print it out to `stdout`:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier
```

Comment: Using backticks with cat is not really portable; really portable way is `$(cat ...)`

Comment: Looks better too. Don't know what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute it, not read it. Do this instead:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier
```